# Enabling mod_status in Apache

Tags: apache, drupal, monitoring

I followed this tutorial to enable `mod_status` in order to monitor apache web server load and page statistics.

Link: http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/

However, this website is running Drupal and I'm a little confused as to how Drupal really works and for some reason when I go to this page:

http://serveripaddress/server-status

I get an error: The site "/server-status" could not be found... I installed phpMyAdmin and never had any issues opening it through

http://serveripaddress/phpmyadmin

Anyone have any idea what could the problem be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a 404 because Drupal is trying to respond to that path.  Take a look at this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/52511

You may want to put this rewrite rule in your vhost configuration instead of Drupal's .htaccess file, because updates to Drupal will cause you to have to remember to patch the .htaccess file each time.